# Adding boolean expressions switch statements in C++?

Tags: c++, boolean, case, break, boolean-expression

I'm practicing switch statements in C++, and I was wondering if I could add a Boolean expression and how, like it's an if/else counterpart. Is it possible to incorporate this?

Here's my skeleton code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <random>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int HouseValue;
    cout << "Enter your total house value estimate:";
    cin >> HouseValue;

    switch (HouseValue)
    {
        case 1:
            (HouseValue < 100000 && HouseValue > 50000);
            cout << "";
            break;
        case 2:
            (HouseValue < 250000 && HouseValue > 100000);
            cout << "";
            break;
        case 3:
            (HouseValue < 500000 && HouseValue > 250000);
            cout << "";
            break;
        case 4:
            (HouseValue < 1000000 && HouseValue > 500000);
            cout << "";
            break;
        case 5:
            (HouseValue < 3000000 && HouseValue > 1000000);
            cout << "";
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: case expressions must be known at compile time.

Comment: I added if's before but my sister said that's not possible so I removed them, and they were acting buggy.

Comment: @Chantola Even if they were there, they're useless in this code. The switch for `case 1:` for example, has already determine `HouseValue` is ... well.. `1`. Testing it for being between 50000 and 100000 is somewhat pointless, since it clearly isn't (its **`1`**).

Comment: Ok, I was just wondering if something like this were possible in a switch statement, and the answer is No. Thank you guys for your super speedy reply

Comment: I don't see how having conditions in the `switch` can be more efficient than the `if()` construct and the `if()` construct is more expressive. So I don't see any benefits tbh. The real power of a `switch` is that the compiler can take advantage of the static nature of the branches (like building a jump table).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't directly use conditions in a switch, since they require a compile time constant expression. In any case you approach is lacking any branch for exact values (eg. `HouseValue == 100000`) and it's redundant.

The simplest solution is to use an `if/else` chain:

```
if (HouseValue < 50000)
  ...
else if (HouseValue < 100000)
  ...
else if (HouseValue < 250000)
  ...
else if (HouseValue < 500000)
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

No. C++ doesn't have this kind of switch structure: `switch` is only used with constants.

The C++ implementation for that control structure is

```
if (HouseValue >= 50000 && HouseValue < 100000) {
   ...
} else if (HouseValue >= 100000 && HouseValue < 150000) {
   ...
} else if (HouseValue >= 150000 && HouseValue < 200000) {
   ...
} else {
   ...
}
```

or, simplifying a bit

```
if (HouseValue >= 50000 && HouseValue < 100000) {
   ...
} else if (HouseValue < 150000) {
   ...
} else if (HouseValue < 200000) {
   ...
} else {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You *can* get creative with the value of the `switch()` eval when deducing your case values. For example:

```
switch((HouseValue + 50000)/50000)
```

will result in the following table of potential results due to [**integer division**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division-in-c):

```
HouseValue (N)           (HouseValue + 50000)/50000
===================================================
0      <= N < 50000                  1
50000  <= N < 100000                 2
100000 <= N < 150000                 3
etc...
```

I won't spoil the fun of figuring out what values to use in the equation to obtain the specific ranges you're looking for (or if its even possible). I will tell you this. Remember that thing mentioned about "falling through" a specific case label to the next if you don't provide a `break` ? Yeah, that may come in handy.

In short, no one said you have to `switch` on the input value directly. You can always use an expression that is based on your input value, so long as the `case` labels are constants, you have lots of room to wiggle.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

No, it can't be done like that.

`switch` statement was not introduced into the language as a mere "syntactic sugar" for chained `if`. `switch` statement was introduced specifically to provide a better-structured replacement for "parametrized goto" functionality, i.e. a `goto` with a run-time jump target, which can be immediately derived from the parameter value. `switch` must always immediately know where exactly to jump. That is the whole idea behind `switch` statement. Your conditions do not fit that idea. (On the second thought, they kinda do, but still they are "too complicated" by the original `switch` standards.)

What you are trying to do is implemented through chained `if`. If you don't like it, you can invent something else, like some sort of range collection that can efficiently generate the integer range index (1, 2, 3 etc.) from a given `HouseValue`. That you will be able to do a `switch` on that index. (See @WhozCraig's answer.)

Of course, since your `HouseValue` is an integer, you can do a `switch` with case labels that cover all possible `HouseValue` values, but this has virtually no value besides purely humorous one.

It should also be noted that some compilers (GCC, for one example) support "ranged" case labels in `swicth` statements, like

```
switch (HouseValue)
{
    case 50000 ... 100000:
        ...
        break;
    case 100000 ... 250000:
        ...
        break;
    ...
}
```

But this is a non-standard language extension.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution, just plug `ValueBracket(HouseValue)` in the switch instead

```
static const std::array<int, 6> Values = { 50000, 100000, 250000, 500000, 1000000, 3000001 };
size_t ValueBracket(int value) {
    return std::lower_bound(Values.begin(), Values.end(), value) - Values.begin();
}
```

and add the following 2 case

```
case 0:
    cout << "you live in a shed peasant, go away";
    break;
default:
    cout << "sorry my Lord, we can't sell your castle here";
    break;
```

An a psychotic case

```
constexpr int Return1() {
    return 1;
}


switch(index) {
case Return1():
        break;
}
```

This might just be GCC that is happy ...

But case can only be compile time constants like constexpr ...

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:  lookup table with function pointers.

```
typedef void (*Ptr_Processing_Function)(void);

void Process_Range_1(void);
void Process_Range_2(void);
void Process_Range_3(void)

struct Range_Entry
{
  unsigned int lower_price;
  unsigned int high_price;
  Ptr_Processing_function process_function;
};

const Range_Entry table[] =
{
  {50000, 10000, Process_Range_1},
  {10000, 15000, Process_Range_2},
  //...
};
const unsigned int entries_in_table =
    sizeof(table) / sizeof(table[0]);

//...
cin >> price;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < entries_in_table; ++i)
{
  if ((price >= table[i].lower_price) && (price < table[i].high_price))
  {
    table[i].processing_function();
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm too late for the party, but you can turn it into a switch like this:

```
int mycase = HouseValue / 50000;

switch (mycase) {
  case 0: /* HouseValue < 50000) */
    ...
  case 1: /* HouseValue >= 50000 && HouseValue < 100000 */
    ...
  case 2: /* HouseValue >= 100000 && HouseValue < 250000 */
  case 3:
  case 4:
  case 5:
    ...
  /* etc */
}
```

This way you trade the (possible) evaluation of 5 if statements against a single int division and a jump. Measure which is faster for your use-case.